# Formatting a letter on textView in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have two pages long letter in textView. And all context of the letter should be shown in device's screen. I'm trying to achieve this by making the font smaller. The problem is that if I copy the letter into textView, it changes the font color to all black and format of the letter becomes weird.

I tried to edit the letter format in Storyboard but it's very hard. When I try to press "Enter" in textView, it doesn't put space between the lines but rather I come out from the textView.

Is textview the best place to put long context of the letter in? If so, how should format the letter in there?

Answer (score 0):

To enter space use Option+Enter and if you are copying from text editor that support formatting then please remove all formatting then copy and paste it. to format text in textview use attributed string.

Comment: One more quick question. Is it possible to use attributed on certain sentence? like on one sentence I center the sentence. On the other one, I change the color of the text to red? If you do not mind, can you give an example in code?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you format it in text editor and save it to a rtf file then, read the rtf into an attributed string, then set the attributedText of the text view? Like:

```
let textURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("MyLovelyLetter", withExtension: "rtf")
let options =[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSRTFTextDocumentType]
let attribText = try! NSAttributedString(fileURL: textURL!, options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
textView.attributedText = attribText
```

for example

[image]

Comment: Do I just format my letter in any texteditor (like apple's default one, textEdit) and save it as RTF?

Comment: Yes, then drag into your project

Comment: throwing me an error saying  '[String : String]' is not convertible to '[NSObject : AnyObject]' on attribText. Thoughts?

Comment: Still throws me an error saying "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'NSAttributedString' with an argument list of type ..."

Comment: I edited my answer. The above code works for me in a swift playground.

Comment: Just tried it and it does not work. Same problem as in storyboard occurs again. I basically gave center alignment on one paragraph with different color. Then, this change is applied to all other paragraphs. Bummer.

Comment: I forgot an exclamation point. It works for me, different colors and different alignment. Maybe post more of the code you're using.